# run all batch scripts in all subdirectories

Tags: batch, ms-dos

I want to run all `x.bat` automatically in all recursive sub directories:

```
C:\test
|   
+---folder1
|      x.bat
|       
+---folder2
|      x.bat
|       
+---folder3
.      x.bat
. 
.----foldern
       x.bat
```

Can be sequentially or simultaneously, it does not matter.

I have this:

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%x in ("*") do (
    pushd "%%x"    
    call "x.bat"
    popd
)
pause
```

But it only runs `x.bat` for `folder1`.

Comment: Can you use a different shell, such as bash?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly on my machine.

I created a test dir with your test.bat and two test dirs in it containing an x.bat:

```
C:\tmp\865348>dir /s /b
   C:\tmp\865348\f1
   C:\tmp\865348\f2
   C:\tmp\865348\test.bat
   C:\tmp\865348\f1\x.bat
   C:\tmp\865348\f2\x.bat
```

These files contain:

```
C:\tmp\865348>type test.bat
   @echo off
   for /r /d %%x in ("*") do (
       pushd "%%x"
       call "x.bat"
       popd
   )
   pause

C:\tmp\865348>type f1\x.bat
   echo "I'm f1"

C:\tmp\865348>type f2\x.bat
   echo "I'm f2"
```

Now to run it:

```
C:\tmp\865348>test.bat
   "I'm f1"
   "I'm f2"
   Press any key to continue . . .
```

Works fine for me. I'd say the problem is in the x.bat in the subdirs. Sure you didn't hardcode "folder1" in all of them somewhere?